# Android Phone broadcast packet while not connected to any AP

Tags: android, wifi, broadcast, packet, smartphone

I am working on an Android WiFi app, and need to know if an app can be created to reliably WiFi broadcast a packet repeatedly while the phone is not yet connected to any access point (AP).  I know the phones can do this natively. For example, when a phone boots up, it sends out packets of "SSID" names to try and make a connection to one of those AP's that are stored in its settings.  I am trying to create code to control a custom piece of electronics device via a smartphone with WiFi broadcast packets.  I can do this now with a TCP/IP connection, but I really don't need the bi-directional (hand-shaking) communications response from the device.  My device and smartphone would be similar to controlling a robot via a smartphone with only uni-directional broadcast packets.  I would send packets to move, or send packets to stop and, etc.  For example, I really don't need to know from the robot that it's turning when I can see it turn.  Another reason for wanting to do this, is that if the Android does not need to try to detect or wait for a handshaking response from the device before continuing, I believe I can obtain a greater WiFi range in poor environmental conditions.

Comment: You need to re-check your assumptions about how WiFi works... many of them are completely false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting your phone to Ad-Hoc mode and talking directly to the robot?  I haven't tested this code but it may work:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(8001);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
socket.setReuseAddress(false);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(databytes, 7,
getBroadcastAddress(), 8001);
socket.send(packet);
```

Comment: I can run it in Ad-Hoc mode but when the robot gets out of range, I have to meet it half way for the WiFi to reconnect.  Maybe it better to think of connecting to a boat and not a robot.

Comment: So the Jame's code did work Steve? Did you solve your problem?